# Create checkout session with multiple items on Stripe using Java

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm getting this error when I click on the URL of the created session:

"Something went wrong
You might be having a network connection problem, or the payment provider cannot be reached at the moment."

Code:

```
 Map<String, Object> paramsPriceIdList1 = new HashMap<>();
        paramsPriceIdList.put2("price", price_id1);
        paramsPriceIdList.put2("quantity", 2);

Map<String, Object> paramsPriceIdList2 = new HashMap<>();
        paramsPriceIdList.put2("price", price_id2);
        paramsPriceIdList.put2("quantity", 2);

List<Object> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
        lineItems.add(paramsPriceIdList1);
        lineItems.add(paramsPriceIdList2);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(
                "success_url",
                "https://example.com/success"
        );
        params.put(
                "cancel_url",
                "https://example.com/cancel"
        );
        params.put("line_items", lineItems);
        params.put("mode", "subscription");

        Session session = Session.create(params);
        System.out.println(session);
```

If I try to use only 1 item, it works.

Comment: Can you update your question with the error returned by the Stripe API (which is likely shown in [the request logs section of the Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs))?  My guess is one of the Price IDs is empty or invalid, but the error from Stripe should point us to next steps.

Comment: I didn't know about that log section, thank you.
I'm not getting any error, the response is 200 with the URL to the checkout, both items work well, the problem start when I try to use different items on the same session checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable names are causing the problem.  For example, you declare `paramsPriceIdList1` but then never add anything to it, and then you have `paramsPriceIdList` which was never declared.  You also have methods that don't exist, like `put2()`.

If you look at the error logs on your server you should see details about these errors.

I cleaned up the variable and method names and this code should work as expected:

```java
Map<String, Object> paramsPriceIdList1 = new HashMap<>();
paramsPriceIdList1.put("price", price_id1);
paramsPriceIdList1.put("quantity", 2);

Map<String, Object> paramsPriceIdList2 = new HashMap<>();
paramsPriceIdList2.put("price", price_id2);
paramsPriceIdList2.put("quantity", 2);

List<Object> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
lineItems.add(paramsPriceIdList1);
lineItems.add(paramsPriceIdList2);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(
        "success_url",
        "https://example.com/success"
);
params.put(
        "cancel_url",
        "https://example.com/cancel"
);
params.put("line_items", lineItems);
params.put("mode", "subscription");

Session session = Session.create(params);
System.out.println(session);
```